# How to add custom layout to linear layout in scrollView dynamicaly

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I want to show a screen with text area that is vertically scrolling and image area that is horizontally scrolling. 
I have created two layouts:

```
activity_display.xml

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/displaySV1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/displayLL1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/displaySV2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/displayLL2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and `custom_layout.xml` : I want to add the custom layout in the linear layout `displayLL1`.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/customFrame">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/customTV1"
        android:layout_gravity="start|top"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Test text"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/customTV2"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:text="Test Value"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="EDIT"
        android:id="@+id/editButton"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Display activity calls:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
LinearLayout linearLayout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.displayLL2);
for(int i = 0; i < count1; i++)
            {
                LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.displayLL1);
                FrameLayout custLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.customFrame);
                TextView label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customTV1);
                TextView value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customTV2);

                label.setText("Test");
                value.setText("Test");
                linearLayout.addView(custLayout);
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < count2; x++)
            {
                final ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
                image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                linearLayout2.addView(image);
            }
```

I am able to populate the image part if text part is commented out. But with the above code nothing is displayed on the screen. 
Any idea where I might be going  wrong? 
Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any exception/error? because *label* and *value* must be null, while you haven't added your *custom_layout.xml* to the activity view.

Comment: Actually I am unable to get the stack trace...my device wont connect with debugger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have a **NullPointerException**.

Because there is no `customTV1` and `customTV2` ids in your activity xml, so calling `findViewById(R.id.customTV1);` will return a null value, and `label.setText("Test");` will throw a NullPointerException.

Actually calling `FrameLayout custLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.customFrame);` will not add your custom xml to the activity one, you need to inflate it.

Try this code:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.displayLL1);
LinearLayout linearLayout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.displayLL2);

LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(yourActivity.this);    

for(int i = 0; i < count1; i++){

    View custLayout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null, false);
    TextView label = (TextView) custLayout.findViewById(R.id.customTV1);
    TextView value = (TextView) custLayout.findViewById(R.id.customTV2);

    label.setText("Test");
    value.setText("Test");
    linearLayout.addView(custLayout);
}

for (int x = 0; x < count2; x++){
  ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
  image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
  linearLayout2.addView(image);
}
```